# SSRS - Conditional Formatting within a lookupset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to dynamically set the color of the returned values within a lookupset function in SSRS? Using the below snippet, I am attempting to include both a line break between results and color code the output on whether or not the result is designated "Active" or not.

```
iif(JOIN(Lookupset("Category A",Fields!curr_Category.Value,Fields!curr_Managed.Value,"Plan_Fees"), "<br />") = "Passive","<font color = 'blue'>", "<font color = 'green'>") +
    JOIN(Lookupset("Category A",Fields!curr_Category.Value,Fields!curr_SecurityName.Value,"Plan_Fees"), "</font>" + "<br />")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. First click inside the textbox and **Right click > Placeholder properties > General > Markup type** and select `HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles`. Then add your styles in the textbox expression like this:;

```
="<font color = 'blue' size = '4'>" & Fields!'ThisIsaField.Value & "</font>"
```

or like this:

```
="<font color = 'blue' size = '4'>" & "hallo1" & "</font>" & " - " &  "<font color = 'red' size = '2'>" & "hallo3" & "</font>"
```

Sure you can wrap this around your `Lookupset()` like you need it.